# Exception with Lombok builder included in stacktrace

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace, lombok

Code is throwing exception using lombok builder:

```
throw MyException.builder().error(ErrorCode.GeneralError).message(error).build();
```

Stacktrace is showing the root of exception as the builder method (`@Builder`)

```
com.MyException
    at com.MyException$MyExceptionBuilder.build(MyException.java:9)
    ...
```

Isn't it lombok issue that builder added to stacktrace ?

Exception  Class:

```
@Builder
public class MyException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7842978360324381658L;
    ErrorCode error;
    RequestVO request;
    ResponseVO response;
    String message;
```

Comment: Please share some more of the error trace. It's not clear what you are trying to do and what error are you getting.

Comment: @fzn the rest of the stacktrace is fine, meaning the line of throw and the methods call it, but I think the builder method shouldn't be part of the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very interesting question indeed, which got me puzzled for a moment. The solution is the following:

> The stack trace is filled in at the point of the exception’s constructor.

If you do not call `fillInStackTrace()` by hand, then Java will fill it in at the point where you call `new`. (Well, the JVM will always fill it in, but it can be overwritten.) Now *where exactly* is your `MyException` constructor called? Yes, in the `build()` function of your builder. Et voilà, that’s what you will see in your stack trace.